# How transfer request body in py_eureka_client

Tags: python, http-post, netflix-eureka

I connect to eureka

```
import py_eureka_client.eureka_client as py_eureka_client

eureka_client = py_eureka_client.init(
                    eureka_server=f"http://{EUREKA_HOST}:{EUREKA_PORT}/{EUREKA_ROUTE}",
                    app_name=f"{APP_NAME}",
                    instance_port=int(PORT))
```

How transfer request body to eureka ?

I tried to do  through headers

```
headers = {'key': 'value'}
response = py_eureka_client.do_service(
            app_name={APP_NAME},
            service={SERVICE},
            headers=headers
        )
# response == None
```

And tried through params

```
query_params = urllib.parse.urlencode(headers)
response = py_eureka_client.do_service(
            app_name={APP_NAME},
            service={SERVICE} + "?" + query_params,
        )
# response == None
```

But all to no avail. Tell me how I can do it?

Through Postman everything works

[exemple request body postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKSkD.png)